# 4-torsion in the dual class group of imaginary quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $-D$ be a fundamental discriminant, and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$. Let $C(-D)$ be the ideal class group of $K$, and $\widehat{C(-D)}$ its dual. The elements of $\widehat{C(-D)}$ are characters $\chi : C(-D) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$.

From genus theory it is known that $\widehat{C(-D)}[2]$ is generated by the real characters $\left(\frac{\cdot}{p}\right)$, where $p$ runs over the prime divisors of $D$, as well as some auxiliary characters involving $2$ and $-1$.

What about $\widehat{C(-D)}[4]$? These are characters $\chi$ mapping into $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Can we characterize all such characters $\chi$, as in the paragraph above? How are they related to the so-called $4$-th power residue symbols?